# How to Integrate JWPlayer in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jwplayer, jwplayer7

Guys i am working on a project where i want to play a video coming from json. I want to use Jwplayer for this purpose please tell me How to Integrate JWPlayer in android studio.

Answer (score 6):

Here we go: 
**Importing the JW Player SDK into your project**

There are two ways to import the JW Player SDK into your Android Studio project. Either through our Maven repository, or by downloading the .aar file from your Dashboard and importing it from your local machine.

1. ***Import using Maven***

   To add the SDK to your Android project using Maven. You must first
   edit your project's build.gradle file and add our Maven repository
   url

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven {
               url 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Next, edit your application's build.gradle file and add the JW
   Player SDK dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
     ...
     compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+'
   }
   ```

   After syncing Gradle you should be able to use all JW Player SDK
   classes in your application.
2. ***Import from your local file system***

   If you do not wish to use our Maven repository you can always
   download our SDK package from your Dashboard and import the SDK from
   your local file system.

   Downloading the JW Player SDK from your Dashboard

   1. Sign in to your JW Player dashboard at https://account.jwplayer.com
   2. Navigate to the Players section, center of the left navigation bar,
      then click on Tools
   3. In the Downloads section, locate the Android SDK and click on the
      download button
   4. Unzip the SDK package to your local hard drive.

   Importing the SDK to your Android Studio Project

   1. Go to File > New > New Module… > Import .JAR / .AAR Package
   2. Navigate to the location where you unzipped the AAR file, select it,
      then click Finish
   3. Go to File > Project Structure…
   4. Make sure your app is selected in the left-hand pane, then click the
      Dependencies tab
   5. Click the plus sign in the lower left-hand corner of the dialog and
      choose Module Dependency
   6. Select the jwplayer-android-sdk module then click OK
   7. Click OK again to close the dialog, the JW Player SDK is now
      available in your project

**Initial Project Configuration**

To ensure proper player behavior the following entries need to be added to your AndroidManifest.xml

First, you must add your JW License Key and nest it within the  element

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="JW_LICENSE_KEY"
    android:value="{YOUR_LICENSE_KEY}" />
```

***{YOUR_LICENSE_KEY}*** should be replaced with the JW Player License Key that is shown in the Tools page of your Dashboard.

Valid license editions include Ads, Enterprise and Trial. The application will crash throwing an AssertionError if an invalid license key is provided.

Next, modify the all  tags that will contain a JW Player and add

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```

This will allow you to handle orientation changes programmatically and will prevent Android from destroying the Activity upon rotation.

**Additional Features**

If you plan to use Google IMA advertising add the line below to the dependencies section of your application’s build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
```

If you plan to use Google IMA ads add the lines below as a child of the tag in your application’s AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

[P.S. Source](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/getting-started/library-project-setup/)

Comment: Took me some time to figure this out, so figured would share. To lock in a version you need syntax like `compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:2.5.3+164'` replacing **+** with **2.5.3+164**. Also it seems that jwplayer has moved away from `jwplayer-android-sdk`  and to `jwplayer-core, jwplayer-common` which is in the [documentation](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/getting-started/library-project-setup/) They moved to this new layout in [Version 2.6](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/about/release-notes/)